# How can I group by values if they are in different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following shape:
[image: DF]

```
State RegionName 1996-04 1996-05 1996-06 1996-07 1996-08 1996-09                                                                                    
CA  Los Angeles 155000.0 154600.0 154400.0 154200.0 154100.0 154300.0
IL  Chicago 109700.0 109400.0 109300.0 109300.0 109100.0 109000.0
PA  Philadelphia 50000.0 49900.0 49600.0 49400.0 49400.0 49300.0
AZ  Phoenix 87200.0 87700.0 88200.0 88400.0 88500.0 88900.0
```

As you can see I have Region and State in rows and **Year-Month** in defferent columns. I need to group the columns into de avg of **Year-Quarter**. How can I do this??

```
State RegionName 1996-Q2 1996-Q3
```

Is it clear ??

Comment: please copy and paste an example of your dataframe and your expected output, we use `pd.read_clipboard` to work with it and help you

Comment: Does that work???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My  approach:**

you must first index all the columns except the ones you want to group:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['State','RegionName'])
#in the original dataframe all columns except columns to group
# df2 = df.set_index(['RegionID', 'State', 'RegionName', 'Metro' ......])
```

---

then you can convert the column strings to `datetime` and then use `to_period` and `groupby`:

```
df2.columns=pd.to_datetime(df2.columns, format = '%Y-%m').to_period('Q')
new_df = df2.mean(level=0, axis=1).reset_index() # to calculate mean by groups
#groups = df2.groupby(level=0, axis=1) # to get groups
print(new_df)
```

---

```
          State RegionName         1996Q2    1996Q3
0           Los    Angeles  154666.666667  154200.0
1       Chicago   109700.0  109333.333333  109050.0
2  Philadelphia    50000.0   49633.333333   49350.0
3       Phoenix    87200.0   88100.000000   88700.0
```

`pd.to_datetime` only necessary if your dates are `str`

Comment: you're right but i don't know if OP needs to apply another function @jezrael

Comment: Yes, agree. Super ;)